# beautifulsoup get value of attribute using get_attr method

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'd like to print all items in the list, but not containing the style tag = the following value: `"text-align: center"`

```
test = soup.find_all("p")
for x in test:
    if not x.has_attr('style'):
        print(x)
```

Essentially, return me all items in list where style is not equal to: `"text-align: center"`. Probably just a small error here, but is it possible to define the value of style in has_attr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the specific style is present in the Tag's style. Style is not considered a [multi-valued attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes) and the entire string inside quotes is the value of style attribute. Using `x.get("style",'')` instead of `x['style']` also handles cases in which there is no style attribute and avoids `KeyError`.

```
for x in test:
    if 'text-align: center' not in x.get("style",''):
        print(x)
```

You can also use list comprehension to skip a few lines.

```
test=[x for x in soup.find_all("p") if 'text-align: center' not in x.get("style",'')]
print(test)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to consider a different approach you could use the :not selector

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<html>
<head>
<title>Try jsoup</title>
</head>
<body>
<p style="color:green">This is the chosen paragraph.</p>
<p style="text-align: center">This is another paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>

'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('p:not([style="text-align: center"])')]
print(items)
```